# How do I add data into html table using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firebase

I'm trying to add data from my firebase realtime database into a html table using jquery and javascript. I'm new to jquery, so I more or less have no idea what I'm doing.
I can retrieve the data but I can't add it to the table on the html page.
Is something wrong with this line?:

```
$("#table_body tbody").append("<tr><td>" + name.Name + "</td><td>" + 
user.Email +  "</td></td></td></tr>");
```

the table_body is just the table's id. The table remains empty.
pls help

Comment: You have two extra `</td>`, although that technically shouldn't stop it working. If you need help debugging the issue we need to see a much more complete example of your JS code, along with the HTML

Comment: Hi minelloe, welcome to SO. Please refer to [mcve] when asking questions in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add things to a table like this:

```
function productsAdd() {
  $("#productTable tbody").append(
      "<tr>" +
        "<td>My First Item</td>" +
        "<td>6/11/2019</td>" +
        "<td>www.itemsite.com</td>" +
      "</tr>"
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this code running on load? Is this code wrapper in:

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

The document must be loaded before jQuery code can run properly, the function above ensures jQuery inside of it runs after the DOM has loaded

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  let arr = [{n:'test', e:'ing'}, {n:'stuff', e:'ok'}];
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    $("#table_body tbody").append("<tr><td>" + arr[i].n + "</td><td>" + arr[i].e +  "</td></tr>");
  }
});
```